# Piece of cloth: bandana?

Tags: vocabulary

What is English word for a piece of cloth worn on the head under a turban?

[image]

That cloth is something like this, that we see this man wearing. But it is worn under a turban.

**Is that piece of cloth called a bandana?**

I don't think because bandana is something else, e.g.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bandanna

Comment: Some people call that style a [bandana](https://www.contrado.co.uk/custom-bandanas). At one time British women wore a similar cloth but tied at the front, called a mob cap (a modern version is still used as medical protection).

Comment: I doubt that there is an English word for it, because turbans are worn by particular ethnic/cultural groups who presumably have their own terminology for their traditional dress.

Comment: Sikhs seem to call it a [patka](https://www.sikhiwiki.org/index.php/Patka) in English as well as Punjabi.

Answer (score 1):

For specific items of clothing that have no history in English speaking countries, we just borrow the term from the native language (sometimes with a change of pronunciation). So we have in English "kimono", "moccasin" and "sari"

Similarly, we have "[patka](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patka)" for the cloth cap, either worn instead of a full turban or under it, particularly by Sikh boys and young men. It is borrowed from Punjabi.